# data.table computing several column at once

Tags: r, data.table

Thank you in advance for reading this. I have a function which was working just fine on data.table 1.9.3. But today I updated my data.table package and my function does not work.

Here is my function and working example on data.table 1.9.3:

```
trait.by <- function(data,traits="",cross.by){
  traits = intersect(traits,names(data))
  if(length(traits)<1){  
    #if there is no intersect between names and traits
    return(      data[,       list(N. = .N),    by=cross.by])
  }else{
    return(data[,c(   N. = .N,
                    MEAN = lapply(.SD,function(x){return(round(mean(x,na.rm=T),digits=1))}) , 
                    SD   = lapply(.SD,function(x){return(round(sd  (x,na.rm=T),digits=2))}) ,
                    'NA' = lapply(.SD,function(x){return(sum  (is.na(x)))})),
                 by=cross.by, .SDcols = traits])
  }
}

> trait.by(data.table(iris),traits = c("Sepal.Length",    "Sepal.Width"),cross.by="Species")
#      Species N. MEAN.Sepal.Length MEAN.Sepal.Width SD.Sepal.Length
#1:     setosa 50               5.0              3.4            0.35
#2: versicolor 50               5.9              2.8            0.52
#3:  virginica 50               6.6              3.0            0.64
#   SD.Sepal.Width NA.Sepal.Length NA.Sepal.Width
#1:           0.38               0              0
#2:           0.31               0              0
#3:           0.32               0              0
```

The point is `MEAN.(traits)`, `SD.(traits)` and `NA.(traits)` are computed for all columns that I give in `traits` variable.

---

When I run this with data.table 1.9.4 I receive the following error:

```
> trait.by(data.table(iris),traits = c("Sepal.Length",    "Sepal.Width"),cross.by="Species")
#Error in assign("..FUN", eval(fun, SDenv, SDenv), SDenv) : 
#  cannot change value of locked binding for '..FUN'
```

Any idea how I should fix this?!

Comment: Report it on the [data.table issues webpage](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** This has been fixed now in [1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) in [commit 1680](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/c3731d8f6a3ca74359e389d0edb70167fa79e2c9). From [NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/README.md):

> 27. Fixed a bug in the internal optimisation of `j-expression` with more than one `lapply(.SD, function(..) ..)` as illustrated [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27495844/559784). Closes #985. Thanks to @jadaliha for the report and to @BrodieG for the debugging on SO.

Now this works as expected:

```
data[,
  c(
    MEAN = lapply(.SD,function(x){return(round(mean(x,na.rm=T),digits=1))}),
    SD = lapply(.SD,function(x){return(round(sd  (x,na.rm=T),digits=2))})
  ), by=cross.by, .SDcols = traits]
```

---

This looks like a bug that manifests as a result of multiple uses of `lapply(.SD, FUN)` in one `data.table` call in combination with `c(`.  You can work around it by replacing `c(` with `.(`.

```
traits <- c("Sepal.Length",    "Sepal.Width")
cross.by <- "Species"
data <- data.table(iris)

data[,
  c(
    MEAN = lapply(.SD,function(x){return(round(mean(x,na.rm=T),digits=1))})
  ),
  by=cross.by, .SDcols = traits
]
```

Works.

```
data[,
  c(
    SD = lapply(.SD,function(x){return(round(sd  (x,na.rm=T),digits=2))})
  ),
  by=cross.by, .SDcols = traits
]
```

Works.

```
data[,
  c(
    MEAN = lapply(.SD,function(x){return(round(mean(x,na.rm=T),digits=1))}),
    SD = lapply(.SD,function(x){return(round(sd  (x,na.rm=T),digits=2))})
  ),
  by=cross.by, .SDcols = traits
]
```

Doesn't work

```
data[,
  .(
    MEAN = lapply(.SD,function(x){return(round(mean(x,na.rm=T),digits=1))}),
    SD = lapply(.SD,function(x){return(round(sd  (x,na.rm=T),digits=2))})
  ),
  by=cross.by, .SDcols = traits
]
```

Works.

Comment: `.(` is the same as `list`. While `.(` is more compact as a code, personally I prefer `list` which is easier for maintaining the code. Personal taste though.

Comment: The problem is I widely used this notation in my functions. 
In current solution it is not obvious which value is the `mean` of for example "Sepal.Length". However, we can add another column and then cast this by extra column, but is there any other way?

Answer (score 2):

Like this ? The output format changed slightly. But the result is all there.

```
trait.by <- function(data,traits="",cross.by){
  traits = intersect(traits,names(data))
  if(length(traits)<1){  
    #if there is no intersect between names and traits
    return(data[, list(N. = .N), by=cross.by])
  }else{
    # ** Changes: use list instead of c and don't think we need return here.
    # and add new col_Nam with refernce to comments below
    return(data[, list(N. = .N,
                       MEAN = lapply(.SD,function(x){round(mean(x,na.rm=T),digits=1)}) , 
                       SD   = lapply(.SD,function(x){round(sd  (x,na.rm=T),digits=2)}) ,
                       'NA' = lapply(.SD,function(x){sum  (is.na(x))}),
                       col_Nam = names(.SD)),
                by=cross.by, .SDcols = traits])
  }
}
trait.by(data.table(iris),traits = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"),cross.by="Species")

# result
      Species N. MEAN   SD NA      col_Nam
1:     setosa 50    5 0.35  0 Sepal.Length
2:     setosa 50  3.4 0.38  0  Sepal.Width
3: versicolor 50  5.9 0.52  0 Sepal.Length
4: versicolor 50  2.8 0.31  0  Sepal.Width
5:  virginica 50  6.6 0.64  0 Sepal.Length
6:  virginica 50    3 0.32  0  Sepal.Width
```

Comment: You might consider pointing out what exactly you changed from the OP's code.

Comment: guess I missed that, sorry

Comment: The problem is I widely used this notation in my functions. 
In current solution it is not obvious which value is the `mean` of for example "Sepal.Length". However, we can add another column and then cast this by extra column, but is there any other way?