# data.table: lapply a function with multicolumn output

Tags: r, data.table, hmisc

I'm using a function `smean.cl.normal` from Hmisc package that returns a vector with 3 values: the mean and the lower and upper CI. When I use it on a `data.table` with 2 groups, I obtain 2 columns and 6 rows. Is there a way to obtain the result with two rows corresponding to 2 groups and separate columns for each of function's outputs, i.e. the mean and CIs?

```
require(Hmisc)
require(data.table)

dt = data.table(x = rnorm(100),
                gr = rep(c('A', 'B'), each = 50))

dt[, lapply(.SD, smean.cl.normal), by = gr, .SDcols = "x"]
```

The output:

```
   gr           x
1:  A -0.07916335
2:  A -0.33656667
3:  A  0.17823998
4:  B -0.02745333
5:  B -0.32950607
6:  B  0.27459941
```

The desired output:

```
   gr        Mean         Lower         Upper
1:  A -0.07916335   -0.33656667    0.17823998
2:  B -0.02745333   -0.32950607    0.27459941
```

Comment: There is probably a better way, but the following works: `dt2 <- dcast(dt[, lapply(.SD, smean.cl.normal), by = gr], gr ~ rowid(gr)); setnames(dt2, 2:4, c('Mean','Lower','Upper'))`

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I did it with dcast as well, it's just I thought there's something in `data.table` that I'm missing.

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494813/data-table-computing-several-column-at-once

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `j` argument in `DT[i,j,by]` expects a list, so use `as.list`:

```
dt[, 
  Reduce(c, lapply(.SD, function(x) as.list(smean.cl.normal(x))))
, by = gr, .SDcols = "x"]

#    gr       Mean      Lower     Upper
# 1:  A  0.1032966 -0.1899466 0.3965398
# 2:  B -0.1437617 -0.4261330 0.1386096
```

`c(L1, L2, L3)` is how lists are combined, so `Reduce(c, List_o_Lists)` does the trick in case your `.SDcols` contains more than just `x`. I guess `do.call(c, List_o_Lists)` should also work.

---

*Comments*

This is quite inefficient for a couple of reasons. Turn on `verbose=TRUE` to see that data.table doesn't like getting named lists in `j`:

> The result of j is a named list. It's very inefficient to create the same names over and over again for each group. When j=list(...), any names are detected, removed and put back after grouping has completed, for efficiency. Using j=transform(), for example, prevents that speedup (consider changing to :=). This message may be upgraded to warning in future.

Also, you are missing out on group-optimized versions of `mean` and other functions that can probably be used to build your result. This may not be a big deal for your use-case, though.

---

When you're applying this to only a single value column, just:

```
dt[, as.list(smean.cl.normal(x)), by = gr]
```

suffices.